# how to echo/print block by block

Tags: shell, terminal, tmux

I just started using tmux and butterfly and I need to scroll one panel.
I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> 
 but it scrolled the whole terminal instead of one panel.

Is there any command line to display my terminal output block by block like describe below ?

- cat foo | ???? -> Display  between line 1-10
- Tab shift, etc -> Display the 10 followings lines
- etc

I did not find anything relevant to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the GNU version of `more` installed:

```
more -d -f -10 foo
```

This displays the file `foo` 10 lines at a time, pausing with a prompt messsage after each 10 lines.  Press <kbd>spacebar</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> at each pause to display the next 10 lines.

You can also press <kbd>h</kbd> or <kbd>?</kbd> at the `more` prompt to see `more`'s other capabilities.

see `man more` for more details.

BTW, if you want to be able to page back and forth within a file, `less` is a better option than `more`.  `more` **can** skip backwards and forwards, but `less` can do it better.  Remember: **less is more**

Comment: you're welcome.  please accept my answer (click on the big tick) if it answered your question, that's how you say "thanks" on this site (comments that say just "thanks" generally get flagged for deletion)